# Error restoring SQL Server backup to a new database

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I created a backup of a SQL Server database named `mydb`. I need to restore it programmatically with a C# code.

The restore must create a new database named `mydbnew`. I'm doing it using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` library.

The code is this:

```
public void RestoreDatabase()
{
    string databaseName = "mydbnew";
    string userName = "user";
    string password = "password";
    string serverName = "(local)\\SQLEXPRESS";
    string sourcePath = @"c:\temp\";
    string fileName = $"mydbbackup.bak";

    ServerConnection connection = new(serverName, userName, password);

    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

    BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new(sourcePath + fileName, DeviceType.File);

    Restore restore = new Restore();
    restore.Database = databaseName;
    restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    restore.NoRecovery = false;

    restore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

    RelocateFile dataFile = new RelocateFile();
    dataFile.LogicalFileName = databaseName + "_data";
    dataFile.PhysicalFileName = databaseName + ".mdf";

    RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile();
    logFile.LogicalFileName = databaseName + "_log";
    logFile.PhysicalFileName = databaseName + ".ldf";

    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(dataFile);
    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(logFile);

    restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);

    restore.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);
}
```

I get an error at `restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer)`:

> Logical file 'mydbnew_log' is not part of database 'mydbnew'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You're telling SQL Server that the database you're restoring has a file called `mydbnew_log` but no such file in the backup exists.

Comment: What is the actual logical name for the log file in the target database `mydbnew`

Comment: @Larnu ok, but I'm trying to tell SqlServer that I need to restore the mdf and ldf files that are in the backup to the new database with a new name: "mydb.ldf => mydbnew.ldf" and "mydb.mdf => mydbnew.mdf". If I remove the Relocate attempt the result is the error: "The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'mydb'."

Comment: Then use need to use the `MOVE` clause, @Tonyc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be 2 issues, first one:

```
    RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile();
    dataFile.LogicalFileName = databaseName + "_log";
    dataFile.PhysicalFileName = databaseName + ".ldf";
```

You are creating a object with name `logFile`, but in the next statement setting values for the old variable.

I expect you want it to be:

```
    RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile();
    logFile.LogicalFileName = databaseName + "_log";
    logFile.PhysicalFileName = databaseName + ".ldf";
```

The next issue, the `LogicalFileName` is the actual logical name in the ***original*** database. But, the `PhysicalFileName` is the ***new*** name.

So, as example, if your DB is like this,

[image],

then the code is like this:

```
        RelocateFile dataFile = new RelocateFile();
        dataFile.LogicalFileName = "Mine";
        dataFile.PhysicalFileName = sourcePath + databaseName + ".mdf";

        RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile();
        logFile.LogicalFileName = "Mine_log";
        logFile.PhysicalFileName = sourcePath + databaseName + ".ldf";
```

The `RelocateFile` uses the logical name of old (original database), but creates file in the new location mentioned in your `PhysicalFileName`

The above code creates file with new name.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, there was a cut&paste error in the code. Thanks a lot for the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I changed the Relocate section with this version:

```
RelocateFile dataFile = new RelocateFile();
dataFile.LogicalFileName = "mydb";
dataFile.PhysicalFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA", "mydbnew.mdf");

RelocateFile logFile = new RelocateFile();
logFile.LogicalFileName = "mydb_log";
logFile.PhysicalFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA", "mydbnew.ldf");
```

Of course I must work to get the paths and names dynamically, but it works.